# android frame over image positioning

Tags: android, image, image-processing, frame, drag

in my application I want to have a frame (with a hole in the middle) and then put it over an image I have captured with the camera or taken from the image library.

I want to show the frame on top, and have the user be able to move with his hand the picture to position it at the right place within the frame and then merge the two images to what the users sees .

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply do that with a framelayouthttp://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html
In this layout you put your ImageView/SurfaceView or what ever, on top (as last frame)
you put the mask in it.

To move the mask, you need to implement a Gesture or do it by hand and overwrite
the functions onTouch/onTouchIntercept to implement your move functions.

Comment: I want the top frame to be stable and to move the picture that shows under the frame to position it. That will be possible right?

Comment: indeed, this should work with a FrameLayout too, its nothing other than a ViewGroup but haves some nice functions to use :)

You only have to capture the touch (gesture) events in your View under the mask.